# How is it possible that I never have to change the batteries of my wireless keyboard?

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, battery

For a long time now I wonder about the lifetime of the batteries I use in my  old wireless keyboard from logitech. I own the wireless keyboard for about 5 years now and never had to change the batteries since then.

It's not really a problem I was just wondering, if it is really normal, that batteries last this long in a wireless keyboard that I use daily for many hours?

I have checked online for the expected duration in general for batteries used in wireless keyboards and the average expected duration is 6 months. So I guess I'm just a little confused, because I measured the voltage of the batteries from time to time and it dropped almost none since the beginning. Kinda spooky xD

Comment: I want some of those batteries!

Comment: @Moab its not the batteries, its the keyboard.  Keyboards last a lot more then 6 months in a battery

Comment: But 5 years?...used daily for many hours.

Comment: @moab - the logitech mk710 claimed 3 year battery life back in 2010. If you put in better then typical batteries and/or typed less (a lot of workloads use mouse not keyboard) its not that much if a stretch.

Comment: @moab the batteries are double AA's from Aerocell, I don't know if they are just cheap in price or if they are just regular batteries as well xD

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer this by contrasting wireless mice with wireless keyboards.

The laws of physics just aren't on a wireless optical mouse's side.

[image]

1. Wireless keyboards don't need to contain any sort of LEDs (and even forego having a caps lock status LED for battery life reasons), whereas wireless optical mice absolutely must be able to illuminate the surface below them with either an LED or laser LED. This illumination *drastically* increases the amount of power drawn by the mouse while it's out of standby mode.
2. Wireless keyboards can employ much more aggressive power saving than wireless mice as they can effectively sleep between keystrokes. Wireless optical mice, even though they dim their tracking LED when the mouse is stationary for a period of time but out of standby mode, must still consume significantly more power than their keyboard counterparts while their tracking LED is even just dimly lit.

Even though keyboards often contain twice as many batteries as wireless mice, their battery life is still typically more than 10x better, so battery capacity alone can't fully explain this discrepancy.

I have a Logitech K830 all-in-one Bluetooth keyboard with built-in trackpad. The battery life through normal use is about 12 months, as the trackpad only consumes a fraction of the power of an optical mouse:

[image]

However, if the keyboard's LED backlight is enabled and illuminates the keys even just while typing is occurring, the battery life suddenly drops from a whole year to just 3-4 days!

The main factor responsible for wireless keyboards' drastically increased battery life as compared to wireless mice is their lack of LED circuitry.

Wireless keyboards, backlighting aside, do not need to concern themselves with LEDs or LED sensors of any sort, and so can effectively return to sleep mode as soon as any key is pressed, whereas a wireless optical mouse would have to remain in a relatively high-power draw state until it returns to sleep mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I already guessed something like that, but I still was just kinda surprised about the time span. The keyboard has 2 slots, each for one AA battery. One thing I forgot to mention, is that the keyboard sometimes stopped working or just worked sparsely but I just switched the two batteries (just the placing in the slots; still the same batteries) and again it continued working for a long time xD

Comment: My keyboard is rechargeable and it surprises me too that I never need to actually recharge it! 

Comment: Hehe :)
The keyboard I was talking about is the K400, but not the Plus one (had to look for it first, because the model number on the keyboard is not visible anymore xD):
https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023307174-Logitech-Wireless-Touch-Keyboard-K400r-Technical-Specifications

Comment: I just checked the back of mine. It's actually a K830! They look quite similar. 

Comment: If you are using the K400 daily for many hours, your results would be unusual. That keyboard/trackpad combo boasts a 1 year battery life. Do you use the built in trackpad? I do observe thatvaerocell batteries are (average performance) Lithium batteries.

Answer (score 2):

Keyboards use very little power. Unlike mice they dont need continually power or LEDs or equivalent, and they transmit a lot less data, so they drain the radio a lot less.

Your belief that a keyboard battery should last 6 months is flawed. Logitech claims a 3 year battery life on many of their wireless keyboards for example, even their inexpensive ones (Eg 
https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/keyboard-k360 )

Also, a keyboard is a much bigger device and typically can fit more batteries. This helps in 2 ways - primarily it can store more energy, but also it can use it more efficiently because it does not need to increase the voltage.

As an indication of how little power keyboards use, look at https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/k750-keyboard which is solar powered and survives months in total darkness.